# How do I allow bootbox to accept multiple lines of code?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, textarea, bootbox

This code works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
bootbox.alert("Hello world!");
</script>
```

This code doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
bootbox.alert("Hello 
world!");
</script>
```

If you're gonna ask why I need it like the second one, it's because that value will be based off of a textarea which has multiple lines of code, I somehow need to make bootbox run with multiple lines of code.

The second one can be a product of a textarea with `Hello` as the first line and `world!` as the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your newlines `\n` to `<br>` using a simple regex:

pseudo code:

```
 textAreaObjectText.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

The `g` flag is necessary here to change all occurrences. We're using `String.prototype.replace` to send the edited text from the textarea to the alert function.

Working example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    bootbox.alert(document.querySelector("textArea").value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<textarea>
Hello
World
We're testing
this
alert
</textarea>
<button>open alert</button>
```

Comment: This has really been insightful, although I do have a question, I tried replacing the bootbox code with "<script type="text/javascript">
bootbox.alert("<?php echo '<textarea>'; ?>" + document.querySelector("textArea").value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />") + "<?php echo '</textarea>'; ?>");
</script>"
I'm just wondering if what can I do to hide the <br />s since my main plan was a textarea inside the modal.

Comment: @CarlEren, I'm lost here. What do you want to do?

Comment: This is mainly for an event calendar feature, if I click a date, a modal appears with a text area and a submit button, after successfully inputting the text into the database, I need to retrieve it for the edit feature. Clicking on a date with an event will show the current textarea details together with an edit button. Clicking that edit button will echo a form of a textarea with its default value as the one saved on the database but it doesn't look pretty as there are <br />s on it and if I make a user use it, it will confuse him/her.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue as you. This is the way I solved it

```
#php code
$comment = json_encode($comment);

#js code
var comment = <?= $comment ?>;

$('#clickSomething').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
bootbox.dialog({
    title: '<span class="text-success">Bootbox Title</span>',
    message: '<div class="form-group"> ' +
             '<label class="control-label" for="project-description">Comment</label> ' +
            '<textarea id="comment" class="form-control" maxlength="1024" rows="8" placeholder="Optional Comment">' + comment + '</textarea> ' +
            '</div>',
```

Answer (score 0):

just put your message with

```
bootbox.alert({ 

    title: "Guardado",
    message: ` Something
    <br>
    else
    `, 
    callback: function(){ window.location.href = 'lista/mensaje'; 
    }
});
```